# How can I access my modem (Arris TG2492) while in briged mode

Tags: networking, router, bridge

I recently installed my own router (Mikrotik) rather than use the Arris. I factory reset the Arris and changed its status to Bridged.

Everything works well.

The Mikrotik and the Arris are on separate subnets (192.168.0.0 -> Arris, 192.168.16.0 -> Mikrotik).

I would like to be able to access the Arris so that I switch off the WiFi Antenna and uncheck its firewall.

Does anyone know if this can be achieved without having to go through the reset process again?

Thanks

Comment: Hook up a computer to your Arris Modem, set the computer to the .16 Arris address. Set your Arris settings. Now disconnect the computer and set it back to DHCP. You probably should restart (not reset) the modem and router

Comment: Not working. I power cycled the Arris (with the Mikrotik unplugged).  I plugged a laptop to the Arris's lan ports and changed the IP of the laptop to 192.168.0.2/24 but all attempt to acces its web interface would return a page not found in IE.

I also attempted to try to get to the Arris via its WiFi port.  Again I manage to connect but no interface.

Comment: You will probably need to try another reset. Disconnect the Router completely, reset the Arris how you wish, including Bridge Mode, restart and set things up again

Comment: I doubt the wifi is still working. My cable modem (also Arris) when set to bridge mode lost all wifi capability. But if yours still has it, the easiest is to just use a wifi capable client, connect to the wifi, then access the Arris' ip address and configure it that way.

Comment: @LPChip: I agree my Arris WiFi is non-functional. I just want to switch off unnecessary WiFi noise. My reasoning is why have two channels (2.4 and 5Ghz) consuming electricity and sending out noise for nothing.  Also since as I'm not sure how the Arris works I would feel better if its Firewall functionality is unchecked.

Comment: I decided to reset the device and adjust those settings that I missed first time round.  As I had documented the settings the process was fast. My only dilemma was whether to disable to DoS protection in the Arris. At the end I decided to disable on the basis that since this was now essentially a black box I would prefer to be in control on the Mikrotik side.  I still feel that the the original question whether one can access and bridged Arris was not answered -- hence my decision not to mark this as being answered.

Comment: If you set any device into bridge mode, things like firewall and wifi are automatically disabled given they are bypassed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I fought with this also, and it seems the Arris does not use the LAN IP but instead appears on 192.168.100.1/24 so... the more you know.

Setting up a static IP in my mikrotik for 192.168.100.2/24 on ether1 let me access the web-interface properly.

Comment: The only way I found to get into the modem was to reset it to defaults and start again.  It would be great if one could export the bridged config but I could not manage it.

Comment: That is how I did the first time also. Then I dug around and found someone mentioning that the Arris modem straight up ignores the IP settings in bridge mode and to try it on 192.168.100.1 instead. Surprisingly worked for my TG2492, but I guess its a hit and miss as they are extremely cheaply built and buggy.

Answer (score 0):

This work fine for me : connect a computer directly with an ethernet cable behind the router. Assign a static ip adress to your computer like 192.168.100.2., same subnetwork mask and default gateway as a dhcp connection. Connect to the router admin panel at 192.168.100.2:8080